# Copy text inside sibling of button without plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to copy the inner text from a sibling of a pressed button, but i'm not succeeding in finding the element.

It is preferred to use JavaScript but i'll accept JQuery answers as well.

The objective is: press de `<a>` and copy to clipboard the inner text of the `<span>`.

So far what i managed is ti copy only the inner html of the `<a>`, naturally.

This is my HTML, i have several of these on my code (i cannot alter the structure of the html only classes and properties)

```
<div class="userpas">
   <a id="abc" onclick="CopyClipboard(this);" class="copy-dynamic" href="#">copy</a> 
   <strong style="color: dimgray">Username:</strong> 
   <span class="a" id="to-copy">password1</span>
</div>
```

The JS (here)

```
function CopyClipboard(element) {

var curElementId = element.id;

console.log(curElementId);


// creating new textarea element and giveing it id 't'
let t = document.createElement('textarea')
t.id = 't'

// Optional step to make less noise in the page, if any!
t.style.height = 0

// You have to append it to your page somewhere, I chose <body>
document.body.appendChild(t)

// Copy whatever is in your div to our new textarea
t.value = document.getElementById(curElementId).innerText;

// Now copy whatever inside the textarea to clipboard
let selector = document.querySelector('#t')
selector.select()
document.execCommand('copy')

// Remove the textarea
document.body.removeChild(t)

//MESSAGE
var el = document.createElement('span'),
       //copy = document.getElementById('to-copy');
       copy = document.getElementById(curElementId);


el.classList.add("message");
el.innerHTML = 'Copied to clipboard';


copy.appendChild(el);


setTimeout(function () {

    el.classList.add("show");

    setTimeout(function () {

        el.classList.remove("show");

    }, 3500);

}, 250);

};
```

**EDIT:**
Context:
This is for internal use of the company, so there is no security issues, these are passwords for webdeploys

Comment: First things first... why do you want to put the password into the clipboard? It seems to be counter intuitive with regards to security... what if it's in the clipboard, then the user leaves the machine, someone else goes on it and presses paste? They get the password of the previous user?!?!?!?

Comment: @PaulZahra Sorry for not providing context, this is for internal use, so there is not security issues

Comment: https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: I cannot use 3rd partys scripts unfortunately...

Comment: Could this answer help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like that for getting the span inner html

```
   var spanElement = element.nextSibling;

   while (!spanElement.tagName || spanElement.tagName !== 'SPAN') {
       spanElement = spanElement.nextSibling
   }

   console.log(spanElement.innerText);
```

Comment: i did this:  ´t.value = document.getElementById(spanElement);
    console.log(t.value);´ but the console log came out and empty line

Comment: the spanElement is the element itself, you dont need to - getElementById(spanElement). just spanElement.innerText